# Правописание прилагательного, образованного от имени собственного

Tags: морфология

"Это вовин фотоаппарат".

Comment: Вовин с большой буквы (притяжательное прил-е, образованное от имени собственного)

Answer (score 3):

Это Вовин фотоаппарат.

Olga неправильно объяснила.

С прописной буквы пишутся притяжательные прилагательные *с суффиксами -ов, -ев, -ин*, образованные от собственных имён: Марсов гнев, Одиссеевы странствия, Машино платье, Шарикова будка.

Но: чеховская пьеса, щедринская сатира.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к Завада. 
Прилагательные с суффиксом -ск- пишутся с маленькой буквы, исключая словосочетания, где они имеют значение "имени или памяти кого-то". 
пушкинские стихи, но Пушкинские чтения.